# Typhoeus with cookies?

Tags: ruby, api, curl, typhoeus

I have to get data out of an API which authenticates with cookies.
Here is it works with curl.

```
curl -L -s -c cookie.txt "http://api.domain.com/login" -d username="user@domain.com" -d password="password"  > /dev/null

curl -b cookie.txt "http://api.domain.com/user_data?param1=value1" > output.xml

cat output.xml
```

The above works well

However I am unable to do the same thing using Typhoeus

I tried the following and it doesn't even authenticate.

```
url = "http://api.domain.com/login"
cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt"
params = {param1: "value1"}
body = {username: "user@domain.com", password: "password"}

request = Typhoeus::Request.new(
  url,
  method: :post,
  params: params,
  body: body,
  cookiejar: cookie_file_path,
  #headers: {Accept: "text/html"},
  verbose: true
)

response = request.run
cookies = CookieJar.new.parse(response.headers_hash["Set-Cookie"])

puts cookies # doesn't show me anything.

url = "http://api.domain.com/user_data"
cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt"
params = {output: "xml"}
body = {}

request = Typhoeus::Request.new(
  url,
  method:        :get,
  params:        params,
  body:        body,
  cookiejar: cookie_file_path,
  cookiefile: cookie_file_path,
  #headers:       {Accept: "text/html"},
  verbose: true
)
```

What am I missing?

```
>>> response.code
302
>>> response.headers_hash
{"Server"=>"squid/3.1.10", "Mime-Version"=>"1.0", "Date"=>"Fri, 14 Jun 2013 02:38:28 GMT", "Content-Type"=>"text/html", "Content-Length"=>"3830", "X-Squid-Error"=>"ERR_INVALID_REQ 0", "Vary"=>"Accept-Language", "Content-Language"=>"en", "X-Cache"=>"MISS from domain.com", "X-Cache-Lookup"=>"NONE from domain.com:3128", "Via"=>"1.0 domain.com (squid/3.1.10)", "Connection"=>"close"}
```

Comment: I dont see the 'Set-Cookie' in header hash at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment but can't. It looks like you're getting a redirect. Try adding the `followlocation: true` option:

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.new(
  url,
  followlocation: true, # <--
  method: :post,
  params: params,
  body: body,
  cookiejar: cookie_file_path,
  #headers: {Accept: "text/html"},
  verbose: true
)
```